# PRISM Xamarin - Working with tabbed pages (IActiveAware)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I have tab pages implementing different views, but I cannot initialize each of the tabs when navigating.

```
<TabbedPage.Children>     
    <tabPages:Page1/>
    <tabPages:Page2/>
    <tabPages:Page3/>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

So what I did was to use `IActiveAware` as prism documentation suggested to know which tab page is currently active. So I have this class:

```
public abstract class TabbedChildViewModelBase : BaseViewModel, IActiveAware, INavigationAware, IDestructible

protected bool IsInitalized { get; set; }

    private bool _IsActive;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsActive;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _IsActive, value, RaiseIsActiveChanged);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler IsActiveChanged;

    public virtual void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {

    }

    protected virtual void RaiseIsActiveChanged()
    {
        IsActiveChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public virtual void Destroy()
    {

    }
}
```

So each child view models inherits the child view model base:

```
 public class Page1 : TabbedChildViewModelBase
 {
    public CurrentSeaServiceViewModel()
    {
        IsActiveChanged += HandleIsActiveTrue;
        IsActiveChanged += HandleIsActiveFalse;
    }

    private void HandleIsActiveTrue(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (IsActive == false)
        {
            TestLabelOnly = "Test";
        }

        // Handle Logic Here
    }

    private void HandleIsActiveFalse(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (IsActive == true) return;

        // Handle Logic Here
    }

    public override void Destroy()
    {
        IsActiveChanged -= HandleIsActiveTrue;
        IsActiveChanged -= HandleIsActiveFalse;
    }
}
```

The problem is, the child vm isn't initializing. Is there something needed in order to implement `IActiveAware` properly nor launching the `IsActive` property

Answer (score 0):

I still used `IActiveAware` unfortunately, to make the `childtabbedviewmodel` work you need to bind the page to its own view model.

So here's what I did:

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
      <views:ChildPage1>
          <views:ChildPage1.BindingContext>
              <viewModels:ChildPage1ViewModel/>
          </views:ChildPage1.BindingContext>
      </views:ChildPage1>
      <views:ChildPage2>
          <views:ChildPage2.BindingContext>
              <viewModels:ChildPage2ViewModel/>
          </views:ChildPage2.BindingContext>
     </views:ChildPage2>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

I used the property `BindingContext` of my views and
using `IActiveAware` I would also know what tab is currently active. Hope anyone helps this who finds trouble binding the child pages of a tab.

Comment: No, you just have to add the ViewModelocator attached property to the child views. The way you are doing it now will not work for injecting services into your VM.

Comment: `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel=”True”` Would it be this one? Sorry new to Prism. Wouldn't it wire automatically if I registered the viewmodels of each child views on `App.xaml` inside `RegisterTypes()`?

Comment: That's it! No, RegisterTypes doesn't do the wiring, its just tell the VML which VM to use.